# Why do I get FALSE when I put $statement->fetchColumn() in while() statement?

Tags: php, pdo

```
$statement = $db->query("select count(*) from myMenu");
$count = 0;
while($count < $statement->fetchColumn())
{
    var_dump($statement->fetchColumn()); //bool(false)
    echo"d";
    $count += 1;
}
//echo : d
```

myMenu table has 6 columns, but while() executes only once when I run the above code.

I even erased var_dump(), but it is still the same.

To solve this problem, I put $statement->fetchColumn() in $count variable like this:

```
$statement = $db->query("select count(*) from myMenu");
$count = 0;
$count_max = $statement->fetchColumn();
while($count < $count_max)
{
    echo"d";
    $count += 1;
}
//echo : dddddd
```

Then it output well.

What did I do wrong in the first code?

I can not understand even if I read the manual of php.net:
http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php

Comment: _"Returns a single column from the next row of a result set or FALSE if there are no more rows."_ - Because you get the value of `count(*)` in the `while()` statement, but since there are no more rows, you will get `false` next time you call it. There are no "next" row, since your query only returns one row.

Comment: Yes, I understand about FALSE of var_dump(), but I still cannot understand why while() executes only once (why not run six times). @MagnusEriksson

Comment: Every time you call the method `$statement->fetchColumn()`, it will return the value of the first column of the current row and then move the cursor to the _next_ row, if there is one. If not, it will return false on every other call.

Comment: Thank you. Probably a little more understandable. FetchColumn() seems to be 'executed' even when used in while() or if () or etc. @MagnusEriksson

Comment: Of course. Otherwise, it would be pointless using them in while/if-etc. :-) The method doesn't care where it gets called from, it will still does it's job.

Comment: If you want to create a loop that iterates as many times as the coun() value, you should use `for ($i = 0; $i < $count_max; $i++) {}` instead.

Comment: Thank you for correcting my common sense. I think your explanation is enough. @MagnusEriksson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [**the doc**](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php),

> `PDOStatement::fetchColumn()` returns a single column from the next row of a result set or **FALSE if there are no more rows**.

Since your SQL query `select count(*) from myMenu` returns **only one row**, the `while()` loop will get executed just once and not six times. And that's because after the first iteration of `while` loop, `->fetchColumn();` statement will return `false` instead of the column value(because there are no more rows left).